# In receiver applications, how come audio tag events don't work?

Tags: chromecast

I'm developing a Chromecast receiver application that plays audio via the <audio> tag.

I can not get the onprogress or onended events to work at all! They do work when I use similar HTML and JavaScript in the Chrome browser on my desktop.

```
        var tagtext = '<audio id="foo" autoplay controls><source src="/file.m4a"/></audio>';

    var element = $(tagtext);
    $('#mediaElement').append(element);
    element[0].onended = function() { moveNext(); };
```

The above code works fine in the Chrome desktop browser, but not the Chromecast!

Comment: Did you check the console log?

Answer (score 0):

The audio tag is valid as a media element for the Receiver.  Look at any of the [Receiver samples](http://github.com/googlecast) and substitute the audio tag for the video tag and it should work.  It should also work with the [default receiver](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default) or the [styled media](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) receiver.